# Is there any way to change the language in ASP.NET MVC without a submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to change the language of my Webpage without having to make the request to the server to keep the "state" of my website (Forms, Chat, ...)
Take the example of a simple page where I change language, but I don't want to lose what is in a form.

File.cshtml

```
@model MVCIdiomas.Models.Persona

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Resource.Resource.AddPerson;
    var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLowerInvariant();
}

@helper selected(string c, string culture)
{
    if (c == culture)
    {
        @:checked="checked"
    }
}

<h2>@Resource.Resource.AddPerson</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SetCulture", "Home"))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Resource.Resource.ChooseYourLanguage</legend>

        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <label for="en-us">
                    <input name="culture" id="en-us" value="en-us" type="radio" @selected("en-us", culture) /> English
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <label for="es">
                    <input name="culture" id="es" value="es" type="radio" @selected("es", culture) /> Español
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="@Resource.Resource.Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller.cs

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    .
    .
    .

    public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture)
    {
        // Validate input
        culture = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(culture);

        // Save culture in a cookie
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
        if (cookie != null)
            cookie.Value = culture;   // update cookie value
        else
        {

            cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
            cookie.Value = culture;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        }
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }                
}
```

Is there any form to do the change without the submit to server ?

Comment: Well, no. Only if you wanna load both webpages at once, every time.

Comment: Regardless of platform, the only way to change content on the client without the browser re-fetching the entire page from the server is to use JavaScript, either by 1) directly manipulating the content on the client through the DOM, or 2) making AJAX calls to fetch individual pieces of content from the server.

Comment: You could load into the local storage

Comment: The hit to the server cannot be avoided, however you can make an ajax call to the controller(server) to post the form & set the culture there asynchronously, this way you wont lose the page state(forms,chat etc) because the whole page wont be reloaded.